# Connecting an Azure Bot to Azure SQL in Python

Tags: python, sql, azure, bots

I am building a bot using the Azure Bot Framework SDK in Python. 
The bot needs to be able to query a SQL DB, also hosted on Azure.

However, when I try to

```
async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(<connectionstring>)
    self.cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from tableA")
    desc = self.cursor.description
```

and send a message to the bot, I get this error, tracked in the "Issues" tab of the bot:

```
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code ServiceUnavailable
```

I have enabled Azure services to get access to the SQL database and triple-checked the connection string. Am I missing something? Is this the right way to query a SQL database from a bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a REST API using Azure Functions to do the queries. Avoids direct queries from the bot, which can be dangerous, and is overall a better and cleaner solution.